# Why is analytics.js required for gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Why is gtag.js including analytics.js if the plan is to 'migrate' from one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

What you are migrating is the syntax, not the underlying technology. The technology is updating and I think will continue to update, but what is required on the users in the end is just an updated syntax.